# Error in running python scripts to initiate subprocess or python threading on server

Tags: python, multithreading, centos, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have two python scripts which I am using to initiate `subprocess`. Following is the structure of my scripts:

**MAIN.py**

This scripts does nothing except initiating the whole process and calling another python script through `subprocess`

```
paramet = ['parameter']
# Calling Subprocess 
result = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"./sub_process.py"] + paramet)
result.wait()
```

**sub_process.py**

This is the script which first executes bunch of SQL statements and then initiate another `subprocess` by calling itself again. The number of subprocess spawned depends on the `parameter` being passed with each `subprocess` call. Also the SQl statements are mostly `insert` statements

```
    conn = connect(host=host_ip, port=21050, timeout=3600)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    sql = "SQL statement"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()

    for col1, col2 in result_set:
        sql = "SQL statement 2"
        cursor.execute(sql)

        sql = "SQL statement 3"
        cursor.execute(sql)

        if col1 == 'para':
               result = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"./sub_process.py"] + paramet)

   result.wait()
```

Now this setup works fine on my local machine but when I am trying to run the same setup on server **it throws following error:**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/dbapi/hiveserver2.py", line 151, in execute
    self._execute_sync(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/dbapi/hiveserver2.py", line 159, in _execute_sync
    self._wait_to_finish()  # make execute synchronous
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/dbapi/hiveserver2.py", line 181, in _wait_to_finish
    raise OperationalError("Operation is in ERROR_STATE")
OperationalError: Operation is in ERROR_STATE
```

When I go to impala UI to check status of queries then I see exception as state. Also on the profile of queries shown as exception it says **"Query Status: Memory limit exceeded"**. But when I execute the same queries from my local machine then there is no exception and everything runs fine.

Even if I execute only one sql statements instead of bunch of sqls the same error comes on server but not on my local machine. I tried to look for some reasons for this but couldn't find anything which might provide the reason for this error.

**I have also tried the python threading and still got the same errors as they were coming with subprocess. The structure of the threading code is same as it is for subprocess above.**

**I have CentOS 6.6, impala 2.0 and impyla 0.9 on my server**

How can I find the reason for this and resolve it? Also what could be a workaround to get the same behavior through other ways if this is not getting resolved? What I basically want is that once a process reaches a certain point in its execution, it should start another process and also continue to keep on executing simultaneously. Once it is done then it should wait for the subprocess to finish before exiting.

Comment: I recommend using multiprocessing. `        if paramet == 'para':
               result = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"./sub_process.py"] + paramet)
` can not work. Can you post the whole error?

Comment: @User that is the whole error that i have posted above in my post. It does not show any other error